# Click on a button in a WebBrowser control

Tags: html, vb.net, dom, getelementsbytagname

HTML Body, Ty For help me.

```
<div class="bottoms_list">
    <div class="One cell">
        <button class="active"><span><i class="Picture"></i></span>1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="Two cell">
        <button class=""><span><i class="Picture"></i></span>2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="three cell">
        <button class=""><span><i class="Picture"></i></span>3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="four cell">
        <button class=""><span><i class="Picture"></i></span>4</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here button (1) is active.

Let's say I want to activate button (2).

I tried:

```
Dim spanpic As String = ""

For Each choice As HtmlElement In Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")

    If choice.GetAttribute("className").Contains("bottoms_list") AndAlso choice.Id.StartsWith("2") Then
        spanpic = choice.Id

        For Each elm As HtmlElement In choice.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")

            If elm.GetAttribute("className") = "button" Then
                elm.InvokeMember("click")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

 '''''''''''''''''
Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

 Try

 For Each elm As HtmlElement In 
 Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(spanpic).Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")

If elm.GetAttribute("className") = "bottoms_list" Then
                If elm.GetAttribute("disabled") = "disabled" Then
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Catch
    End Try
```

That's all I know, and I don't have good experience with element ids......................................

Comment: Please tells us the results of debugging this code. When you step through it, do any of the lines get hit?

Comment: it show nothing, nothing hit.

Comment: Not even the first line? The `For Each choice...` line? Then there's something very wrong with your code. Perhaps you have this code in a function that you're not calling? Please provide a [mcve] that shows how you call this code.

Comment: Hello You are right my code was not completed,

Comment: i cant edit my question i dont know why,

Comment: @HereticMonkey , Done, i edited code now , hope all be clear, big ty for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
"get collection of all div in the webpage"
For Each divSect As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")

    "get the div which has the tag of Two Cell"
    If divSect.OuterHtml.Contains("Two Cell") then

        "get the button inside the div which has the tag of Two Cell"
        For Each elem as HtmlElement In divSect.children
        If elem.GetAttribute("className") = "button" Then
            elem.InvokeMember("click")
        End if
        Next
    End if    
Next
```

I hope those code could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

look I'm not an expert either, but if you want to set a class "active" to the pressed button, then you should use class binding techniques in most of java-script frameworks.

For me I use VueJs and here's how I would do it:

HTML Body:

```
<div id="myList">
  <div class="bottoms_list">
    <div class="One cell">
      <button @click="isActive = 1" :class="{active: isActive == 1}"><span><i class="Picture"></i></span>1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="Two cell">
      <button @click="isActive = 2" :class="{active: isActive == 2}"><span><i class="Picture"></i></span>2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="three cell">
      <button @click="isActive = 3" :class="{active: isActive == 3}"><span><i class="Picture"></i></span>3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="four cell">
      <button @click="isActive = 4" :class="{active: isActive == 4}"><span><i class="Picture"></i></span>4</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then your Vue instance should look like this :

```
new Vue({ 
  el: '#myList',
  data: {
    isActive: 0,
  },
});
```

You can optimize this code to one line using the v-for directive.

Comment: But i think its C#, What if VB.Net